# Java Unit Tests of components that uses Firebase

Tags: java, firebase, maven, unit-testing

I'm working on a project where we use Firebase to store data and we're doing some unit tests. I have set a GitHub Action that executes mvn package and mvn test on every push or pull request, and the problem is that I receive the following error when it executes tests:

> java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.

I have created the secret with the .json and this is how I wrote the GitHub Action:

```
name: Maven CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches: [ develop ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ develop ]

jobs:
  build_and_test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
            
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 15
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 15

    - name: Cache the Maven packages to speed up build
      uses: actions/cache@v1
      with:
        path: ~/.m2
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-m2-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
        restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-m2      

    - name: Build project with Maven
      run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
      env: 
        GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS }}
    
    - name: Run (J)Unit tests
      run: mvn clean test
      env:
        GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS }}
```

Comment: Trying to separate things which are not sepearted. Runngin `mvn package` and `mvn clean test` does not make sense... repeats several parts. because `package` life cycle includes `test`... Furthermore you are using an old version of the github actions cache (check the location of actions/cache)... Furthermore the docs about google saying that the variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS points to a file ... ?

Comment: Yeah, I’ll update the action! Yes, but it’s a .json file!

Comment: The error message states something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that it somehow wasn't using the updated version of the action. Anyway, I solved using google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@master set as follow:

```
- uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@master
      with:
        project_id: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}
        service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY }}
        export_default_credentials: true
    - name: Set GCP credentials
      run: gcloud info
```

GCP_PROJECT_ID contains the project id and GCP_SA_KEY contains the service account .json file obtained from Firebase.